# How to delete drawn objects with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

How to delete drawn objects with OpenCV in Python ?

1. I draw objects on click (cv2.rectangle, cv2.circle) ...
2. Then I would like to delete only drawn objects.
   I know that i need to make a layer in behind of the real image and to draw on another one.
   But I do not know how to implement this in code.

Comment: Draw on a copy of the original and replace that image with the original when you want to erase all objects that have been drawn

Comment: I must delete with eraser, sometimes i do not need everything to erase.

Comment: I do not think you have much choice. OpenCV does not draw on a graphics channel. I do not know of any way to erase drawing on an image after the image pixels have been replaced by the drawing color. You can do inpainting, but you would need to create a mask for only the parts you want erased and then that is not a perfect erasure.  But see cv2.inpaint().

Answer (score 0):

Have a method or something that when it's executed, will replace the image with stuff drawn on it with an original unaltered image. It's best to create a clone of your original image to draw on.